# How do we add "InputAccessoryItem"s in Swift UI?

Tags: swiftui

Using SwiftUI and running into an issue with the keyboard. I want to use the .deicmalPad but I can't dismiss it since it has no "return" button.

Found a workaround: use UIApplication.shared.windows[0].endEditing(true) on a button. (Tried using it on the viewController for the app but it broke NavigationLinks)

Now I want to add the "Next", "Previous" and "Submit" strip above the keyboard, like in this picture: http://brainwashinc.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/07/Simulator-Screen-Shot-Jul-28-2017-9.07.42-AM.png

can't find SwiftUI documentation for this feature, only finding incompatable UIKit solutions involving inputAccessoryView and it's items.

Ultimatly want to use the "Submit" button's event to use UIApplication.shared.windows[0].endEditing(true) and *finally* get the keyboard to go away.

Thanks in advance